# Optimizing generating random number in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a two 1 by 10^3 matrix which its elements change in each step of the loop of simulation. To find a new element in each for loop step, I need 2*1000 Gaussian random numbers. the number of loop steps is equal to 10^5. Which method is less time-consuming in this case?

1. creating two 10^5 by 1000 random matrix before for loop and call them inside the loop.
2. creating two 1 by 10^3 random matrix in each step of the loop?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39251206/3372061

Comment: Because there are lots of stuff in the for loop and if I ran the code, it takes hours to give me the output@EBH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little code to answer your question:

```
function rnd_time_test
rnd_test = @(n) randn(2,n,1000);
N = 1e5;
one_time = timeit(@() rnd_test(N))
loop_time = timeit(@() rnd_test_loop(N))

    function R = rnd_test_loop(n)
        for k = 1:n
            R = randn(2,1000);
        end
    end
end
```

and the result:

```
one_time =
      2.245
loop_time =
      1.6311
```

So, **on my machine**, using a loop is faster.